# How do I stop a servo motor at the current position when using a serial port? I want it to remain in one position when receiving "0"

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, servo, code-review, serial-data

I am working on a project where I would like values received from an Xbox Kinect will activate components on my Arduino. Currently, I am trying to get a servo motor to turn on and rotate when the value is "1" and to remain in one position (currently written as 120degrees) when the value is "0". However, I can turn on the motor and initiate rotation just fine, but when I let go of the mouse (and it shows that the value "0" is being sent in Processing and on the Serial Monitor), the motor just keeps spinning. This is my current code:

```cpp
char val; // Data received from the serial port
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available())
  { // If data is available to read,
    val = Serial.read(); // read it and store it in val
  }
  if (val == '1') { // If 1 was received
    Serial.print ("1");// turn the LED on
    for (pos = 0; pos <= 120; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
      // in steps of 1 degree
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    }
    for (pos = 120; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
      myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    }
  }
  if (val == '0') {
    Serial.print ("0");
    pos = 120;
    myservo.write(pos);
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic of your sketch is to move from 0 to 180 and back when receiving the character '1'. The movement is completed before checking for the next character. Your sketch does not allow stop at the current position during the movement.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the mouse is not sending a continuous stream of 1s? If that were the case then, because of buffering, all the 1s will serviced before the servo stops. For example, a sequence of 11111 followed by a 0 will cycle the movement 5 times before it stops and prints the 0.

Answer (score -1):

fairly simple:

```
switch (serial_received()) {
  case -1: break; //-1=nothing received
  case  0: break; //0 received
  case  1: servo_pos = ...; servo_move2(servo_pos); break; //update servo position
  case  .... //other commands
  default: ...
}
```

you can fill in the functions with whatever appropriate for your environment.